# Schengen visa for Indian passport holder in Saudi Arabia

Tags: visas, schengen

Can an Indian passport holder staying in Saudi Arabia on a visit visa (multiple-entry 2 years validity) apply for a Schengen tourist visa from Saudi Arabia?

Please guide me with the process.

Comment: Which Schengen country(ies) do you want to visit?

Comment: Will be visiting Greece only

Answer (score 1):

Unless in exceptional circumstances, Schengen visas must be applied for *in the location where the applicant resides*.

It sounds like your status in Saudi Arabia doesn't allow you to take up residence there. If that is true, a Schengen country's consulate in SA would refuse to process a visa application from you.

Comment: though am not a resident but my husband works here ....but am on visit visa , which is valid for two years that means i can exit and enter the country multiple times over a period of 2 years....Am confused if i still need to apply for schnegen visa from India or can apply from Saudi Arabia itself?

Comment: @skk: It is of course possible that Saudi Arabia names their short term residence permits confusingly. If so, local consulates should be aware of the actual meaning (which is one of the reasons to require applications to be filed in the applicant's country of residence!). To be sure, contact the relevant consulate directly for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your response...i will be getting in touch with the Greece embassy here.

Comment: @skk among the "exceptional circumstances" are planned absences from the place of residence that are longer than 3 months' duration, because the earliest one may apply for a Schengen visa is three months before traveling to the Schengen area.  If you won't be in India during the three months before your trip to Greece, and you will be in Saudi Arabia with your husband during that time, the Greek consulate should (in theory at least) accept your visa application.